# Comprobar existencia de un directorio

Tags: android

tengo un problema y es que no puedo comprobar la existencia de una lista de direcciones obtenidas de un archivo JSON usando retrofit.

Este es parte de mi código:

```
@Override
public void success(HypedModelsResponse hypedModelsResponse, Response response){
    int cantn = hypedModelsResponse.getModels().size();
    Log.e("Cantidad", String.valueOf(cantn));
        for (int i = 0; i <cantn ; i++) {
            String directory = String.valueOf(hypedModelsResponse.getModels().get(i).getModelos());
            list.add(directory);
        }
    CheckFile();
}

public void CheckFile(){
    int i = 0 ;
    for (String directory : list){
        File file   = new File(directory);
        if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()){
            Log.e("Existe", list.get(i));
            break;
        }else {
            Log.e("No existe","el directorio no existe");
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Josue, has visto que cuando llama el método CheckFile() que list tenga valores. Que valores tiene list en ese punto?

Comment: Bienvenido! Te invito a pasar por el [tour de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link para tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de recibir una respuesta.
Si has encontrado una respuesta por tu cuenta, puede que te interese ver [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Josue puede ser que el problema sea el `break` en `CheckFile` ? Al ejecutar el `break` automaticamente salís del ciclo `for`.

Comment: Gracias por las respuesta, solucioné el problema.
El problema estaba en acá:

String directory = hypedModelsResponse.getModels().get(i).getModelos();

Retornaba un String comillas y File no reconoce las comillas entonces solo reemplacé las comillas.
 
String directorio = directory.replace("\"", "");

Y se solucionó. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void success(HypedModelsResponse hypedModelsResponse, Response response){
    int cantn = hypedModelsResponse.getModels().size();
    Log.e("Cantidad", String.valueOf(cantn));
        for (int i = 0; i <cantn ; i++) {
            String directory = hypedModelsResponse.getModels().get(i).getModelos();
            String directorio = directory.replace("\"", "");
            list.add(directorio);
        }

    CheckExists();

}

public void CheckExists(){
    int i = 0 ;
    for (String directory : list){
        File file   = new File(directory);
        if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()){
            Log.e("Existe", list.get(i));
            break;
        }else {
            Log.e("No existe","el directorio no existe");
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```